# How to allow AD group to run elevated commands from the desktop in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, sudo, users, desktop-environments, active-directory

I've seen a number of similar questions, but none that quite cover my situation.

I have an Ubuntu desktop 22.04 system, setup for authentication against a Active Directory.  I have a domain group added to `sudoers.d` via `%group@domain ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL`.  That allows the group members to use sudo at the command line, which works fine.

However, it doesn't allow those users to access elevated commands from the desktop (for example, installing software packages or accessing system configuration).  That appears to rely on the sudo user group, not the sudoers list.  Adding an individual domain user to the sudo user group via `usermod` allows that user to run elevated gui commands, but this obviously doesn't work for the whole group.

Can I add or link an entire AD user group to the local sudo group?  Or is there another way to grant an AD group access to elevated commands from the desktop gui?